# /bin/sh: 1: go: not found , but `go` is clearly in the PATH variable

Tags: go, lightning-network

Been pulling out my hairs on this one, it must be so simple but for some reason I can't get it to work..

I'm using go1.15, on Ubuntu 18.04, trying to build lnd from source off of github.

I run `sudo make install` after all the preliminaries but keep getting error

```
GO111MODULE=on go install -v -tags="" -ldflags " -s -w -X github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/build.Commit=v0.11.0-beta-199-g98da919bf1c421dd4a976506761e626e39384a8d -X github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/build.CommitHash=98da919bf1c421dd4a976506761e626e39384a8d -X github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/build.GoVersion= -X github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/build.RawTags=" github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/cmd/lnd
/bin/sh: 1: go: not found
Makefile:139: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 127
```

i have `GOPATH=/usr/local/go` and have added `/usr/local/go/bin` to my PATH variable

can't understand what i am doing wrong
`go version` returns normally

I'm an intermediate programmer, but been using Linux for many years and do not understand what is going on.